# Отбор строк по заданным параметрам в массив

Tags: excel, vba, макрос

Коллеги!
Вылетает код (out of range) при выводе строк из массива в новый лист (я вообще даже не уверен, что с формированием массива всё в порядке):

```
Sub BKFindDeviations()

Dim Deviations() As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim Mnth1 As Date
Dim Mnth2 As Date
Dim MnthRowCounter As Long
Dim LoopCounter As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim k As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Mnth1 = "01.01.2020" 'Mnth1 = InputBox("Ââåäèòå ïåðâîå ÷èñëî ìåñÿöà, êîòîðûé áóäåò ñðàâíèâàòüñÿ ñ ïðîøëûìè ìåñÿöàì (ôîðìàò: dd.mm.yyyy")
Mnth2 = "01.02.2020" 'Mnth2 = InputBox("Ââåäèòå ïåðâîå ÷èñëî ìåñÿöà, êîòîðûé áóäåò ÿâëÿòüñÿ áàçîé äëÿ ñðàâíåíèÿ (ôîðìàò: dd.mm.yyyy")

For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))
    If r.Offset(0, 8).Value = Mnth1 Or r.Offset(0, 8).Value = Mnth2 Then
        MnthRowCounter = MnthRowCounter + 1
        ReDim Preserve Deviations(1 To 17, 1 To MnthRowCounter)
        For LoopCounter = 1 To 17 'Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlToRight))
            Deviations(LoopCounter, MnthRowCounter) = r.Offset(0, LoopCounter - 1).Value
        Next LoopCounter
    End If
Next r

'Deviations = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

Worksheets.Add

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(UBound(Deviations, 1) - 1, UBound(Deviations, 2) - 1)).Value = Deviations

Erase Deviations

Set rng = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

'×èñòèì ôîðìàò
With rng
    .ClearFormats
End With

'Óñòàíàâëèâàåì ôîðìàò "Äàòà" â ñòîëáöå Äàò
For k = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    'If Cells(r, 9) Like "##.##.####" Then
        'Cells(r, 9) = DateSerial(Right(Cells(r, 9), 4), Mid(Cells(r, 9), 4, 2), Left(Cells(r, 9), 2))
        Cells(k, 9).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy;@"
    'End If
Next k

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic End Sub
```

Значения задействованных в операторе переменных перед "вылетом":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновил код

Comment: Могу файл с данными приложить... если нужно..

Comment: *Вылетает код (out of range) при выводе строк из массива в новый лист* На какой именно строке кода вылетает? Каковы в этот момент значения задействованных в операторе переменных?

Comment: Да нет, данные, скорее всего, не понадобятся... Но прежде чем будем обсуждать код - а альтернативный способ не подойдёт? Ведь фактически это обычный фильтр по двум значениям с копирование результата в новый лист, нет? Так почему бы не записать это всё с помощью `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter` и просто перенести результат с помощью, например, `.Cut - .Paste`?

Comment: Да. Всё верно. В принципе автофильтр как вариант. Но хочется функционалом массивов отойти.. Автофильтр думаю будет следующий шаг, так как это только часть задачи...

Comment: Картинку ща попробую вставить. Вылетает сразу после добавления листа (Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(UBound(Deviations, 1) - 1, UBound(Deviations, 2) - 1)).Value = Deviations)

Comment: Ну да, `For Each r In Range...` ничего не присвоил `r`. Предполагалось, что `r` будет очередной строкой диапазона? Ячейкой? Ячейкой первой колонки?

Comment: Да. Всё правильно. Поясню... Предполагалось, что вся строка (полностью слева направо) удовлетворяющая дате заходит в массив

Comment: Обновил код. Теперь получается какой-то транспонированный и кривой результат...

Comment: Дайте ссылку на файл

Comment: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ6EMnXZTjwQX9Rp8VbsNPMnhHTUrFV8CnN7

Comment: Там регистрироваться надо...

Comment: ща. Момент. Сделаю

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1391q4_nd853CUkBwuoVi6c1gA01bF0UY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "Транспонированный" - это понятно: Deviations заполняется (колонки, строка), а нужно бы наоборот (строка, колонки). Но тогда засада с `ReDim Preserve` - изменить-то можно только последнее измерение. Как насчет того, чтобы в массив собирать не все данные с листа, а только номера подходящих строк, а в конце опять циклом все нужные строки скопировать "как есть" в целевой лист? В этом случае массив может быть одномерным и `ReDim Preserve` отработает без проблем. Опять же, если копировать ячейки с исходного листа, то и дополнительное форматирование не понадобится.

Comment: Сможешь код поправить по своей идее?

Comment: Спасибо! не увидел сразу код. Проверил: всё работает!

Comment: Работает, но как-то слишком многословно получается - с фильтром лаконичнее, и читать легче, и при случае исправлять проще

Comment: Тут соглашусь... Надо протестить на большом количестве строк... Также это только часть задачи... Есть ещё задумка: с начала всё сворачивать по категориям (17-й столб), потом смотреть отклонение Mnth1 от Mnth2 и если отклонение выше заданного уровня (задаётся входящим параметром), то тогда отбирать только те категории (свёрнуто), которые отклонились выше заданного уровня и выгружать по ним строки (это как раз и покрыто этим вопросом на SOF). Как-то так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы всё-таки рекомендовал переключиться на использование автофильтра прямо сейчас - получится и короче, и проще, и - я так думаю - надёжнее

```
Sub BKFindDeviations()
Dim Mnth1 As String, Mnth2 As String
Dim aRng As Range, aDest As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Mnth1 = "01.01.2020" ' Или с помощью InputBox()
Mnth2 = "01.02.2020"
    Set aRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set aDest = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A1")
    aRng.AutoFilter
    aRng.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="=" & Mnth1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & Mnth2
    aRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=aDest
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    aRng.AutoFilter
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Разумеется, можно перебрать и каждую из строк по одной, отбирая нужные для последующего копирования. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
Sub BKFindDeviations()
    Dim aRows() As Long
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim src As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim Mnth1 As Date
    Dim Mnth2 As Date
    Dim MnthRowCounter As Long
    Dim LoopCounter As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Mnth1 = "01.01.2020"
    Mnth2 = "01.02.2020"
    Set srcSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set src = srcSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For Each aCell In Intersect(srcSheet.Columns(9), src).Cells
        If aCell.Value = Mnth1 Or aCell.Value = Mnth2 Then
            MnthRowCounter = MnthRowCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve aRows(1 To MnthRowCounter)
            aRows(MnthRowCounter) = aCell.Row
        End If
    Next aCell
    
    Worksheets.Add
    Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    src.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=aCell ' Строка заголовков
    Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
    For LoopCounter = LBound(aRows) To UBound(aRows)
        src.Rows(aRows(LoopCounter)).Copy Destination:=aCell
        Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next LoopCounter
    Erase aRows
    Columns.AutoFit
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное Джонсан! Но у меня ещё и меркантильный интерес - хочу понять где мои скилзы по массивам проседают. Но Ваш код обязательно потестю!! Ещё раз огромное спасибо!! -))

Comment: Да. Код рабочий. Только там 9-е поле надо поставить вместо 10-го...

Comment: Как насчёт того, чтобы крутить цикл `For Each r` не по всему диапазону, а указать что речь идёт о .Cells? Опять же, по первой колонке или сразу по 9-ой? Тогда и .Offset в If не понадобится

Comment: Ща дождусь Виктура... Он вроде файл запросил... Может прольёт свет -))

Comment: Открыл, запустил. Лист создан, ошибки `out of range` нет.

Comment: ок. То есть по ходу код рабочий что ли? -))

Comment: Транспонирование не нужно!